# Meteor Package api.add_files add entire folder

Tags: meteor

I would like to add an entire folder of files to my package.  Instead of adding each file individually, is it possible to add an entire folder of files using api.add_files in the package.js file?  Perhaps something like:

```
Package.on_use(function(api) {

api.add_files(["files/*","client");

});
```

Answer (score 17):

I don't think there's something like that currently in the public API.

However, you can use plain old Node.JS to achieve what you want to do.

Our package structure looks like this :

```
/packages/my-package
    |-> client
    |   |-> nested
    |   |   |-> file3.js
    |   |-> file1.js
    |   |-> file2.js
    |-> my-package.js
    |-> package.js
```

We build a helper function as follow :

```
function getFilesFromFolder(packageName,folder){
    // local imports
    var _=Npm.require("underscore");
    var fs=Npm.require("fs");
    var path=Npm.require("path");
    // helper function, walks recursively inside nested folders and return absolute filenames
    function walk(folder){
        var filenames=[];
        // get relative filenames from folder
        var folderContent=fs.readdirSync(folder);
        // iterate over the folder content to handle nested folders
        _.each(folderContent,function(filename){
            // build absolute filename
            var absoluteFilename=folder+path.sep+filename;
            // get file stats
            var stat=fs.statSync(absoluteFilename);
            if(stat.isDirectory()){
                // directory case => add filenames fetched from recursive call
                filenames=filenames.concat(walk(absoluteFilename));
            }
            else{
                // file case => simply add it
                filenames.push(absoluteFilename);
            }
        });
        return filenames;
    }
    // save current working directory (something like "/home/user/projects/my-project")
    var cwd=process.cwd();
    // chdir to our package directory
    process.chdir("packages"+path.sep+packageName);
    // launch initial walk
    var result=walk(folder);
    // restore previous cwd
    process.chdir(cwd);
    return result;
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```
Package.on_use(function(api){
    var clientFiles=getFilesFromFolder("my-package","client");
    // should print ["client/file1.js","client/file2.js","client/nested/file3.js"]
    console.log(clientFiles);
    api.add_files(clientFiles,"client");
});
```

We simply use Node.JS [fs utils](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to work with the file system.

Comment: This is a far better alternative for now than listing out the directory manually https://github.com/nooitaf/meteor-semantic-ui/blob/master/package.js

Comment: Is there a good way to package this code for re-use across multiple packages without relying on NPM? Putting this in a Meteor package itself doesn't seem the way to go since this code is called prior to the loading of all packages. And there doesn't appear to be a good of loading a raw NodeJS module outside of packaging it for NPM.

Comment: Is it just for me that this breaks during `meteor publish --create`?