# Is it possible to make rules for filenames to serve only to client or to server?

Tags: meteor

Meteor has special directories: `server` and `client` for serving files only to server or only to client.

Is it possible to make similar behaviour, but using not client and server folder names but file names which end with either `.client.js` or `.server.js`?

For example `collections.client.js` would be available only on client and `collections.server.js` would be available only on server?

**UPD**
Maybe it is possible to create smart package which will take control of files serving?

Comment: It's not possible. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It would keep file structure flat: `collections.client.js`, `collections.server.js`, `collections.mutual.js` instead of `server/collections.js`, `client/collections.js`, `mutual/collections.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, what you can do however, is the following :

`lib/collections/collection.js`

Declare the collection and common client/server behavior such as `Meteor.methods`.

`client/collections/collection.js`

Declare client specific helpers regarding the collection.

`server/collections/collection.js`

Declare publications and other server-side helpers.

You could alternatively declare everything in `lib/collections/collection.js` and use `Meteor.isClient` and `Meteor.isServer` blocks.
This might be OK for very small files but it can quickly become a mess for larger projects.
I'm not sure if the Meteor build tool is smart enough to strip `Meteor.isServer` from the bundle served to the client.

---

You can also use a modular approach and use packages instead, with the `Package` API you can control precisely the context where a file is supposed to be executed.

```
Package.describe({
  name: "my-app-module",
  description: "Handles some feature in My App",
  version: "1.0.0"
});

Package.onUse(function(api){
  api.addFiles({
    "my-module/shared.js"
  },["client","server"]);
  //
  api.addFiles({
    "my-module/client.js"
  },"client");
  //
  api.addFiles({
    "my-module/server.js"
  },"server");
  //
  api.export("MyModule",["client","server"]);
});
```

Comment: I checked Meteor build tool, it does not cut off `Meteor.isServer` blocks for the client

Comment: Then rely on the `client/` `server/` method, I'm not sure what's the use case for your question anyway ?

Comment: The reason is just convenience. My application is splitted into "blocks".  Every block has its own folder. Some blocks run on the server some on the client and some on both locuses. So instead of creating client/server/mutual subdirectories for every block I would prefer to keep flat structure

Comment: I think your "blocks" concept falls into the Module pattern and you should probably create a dedicated local package for each block then, see my edit.

Comment: Intresting. Maybe you know if `.addFiles` supports wild-cards? For example: `api.addFiles("my-module/*.server.js", "server")`. I've checked meteor's docs and found no word about it

Comment: It does not, every file has to be declared. It's hardly a problem though, you're likely to spend way more time designing your module than writing the proper `package.js` to declare it properly.

Comment: Thank you, @saimeunt, will try packages-approach

Comment: You could put all your server files inside `my-module/server/` and add the entire folder using something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793505/meteor-package-api-add-files-add-entire-folder/20794116#20794116

Comment: hmm... very interesting. Seems like using npm's `fs` module I can add files not only in `server` folder but files ended with `.server.js` or any other rule I want

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, for now you can't do this, but you can put your code in

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // your server code
};

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // your client code
};
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, but the bad part of this solution is that client's javascript weight will be increased